# override existing open tabs in RStudio with same names

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a possibility in RStudio to check when using `View(dataframe)`, if there is already an open dataframe (tab in RStudio) with the same name? When yes, would like to override the existing one. Otherwise you will have 2 tabs open with the same dataframe-name.

Thanks for any help.

[image: tabs]

Comment: Maybe upgrade to the latest RStudio (v1.2.5033) because I only get the one data tab open. This may be a new feature.

Comment: I do have already the newest version 1.2.5033.